texlive miktex conflict - texhash
I'm working with Ubuntu 22.04 and texlive (I'm using the Ubuntu texlive from tug.org). I tried to install miktex but gave up because I could not finalize the installation of the miktex console, which would have allowed me to finalize the complete installation.
Since I uninstalled miktex, the texhash command no longer works.
sudo texhash

the terminal answers me:
texhash: error while loading shared libraries: libmiktex-setup.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

However, I uninstalled miktex using the dedicated page and reinstalled texlive.

I wouldn't use miktex on ubuntu. Most users will use texlive, so it is much better tested and even on windows, miktex seems to have more packaging errors than texlive.

Are you using the ubuntu texlive or a vanilla texlive from tug.org?
